# Can JS callback functions ever return a value?

Tags: javascript, callback

I totally understand why a callback function can't return a value if the logic inside the callback is doing or fetching something on an external server.

What I don't quite get is why does a callback function not return a value if everything inside the callback function is normal, synchronous code:

```
var myFunc = function(input, callback){
  var sum = input + 10;
  callback(sum);
};

sum = myFunc(1000, function(input){
  console.log(input);
  return input + 9000;
});
```

`sum` still returns undefined, even though the `console.log` logs a value of 1010.

Is it a hard and fast rule that callbacks can NEVER return anything?

And do all callbacks in other languages also never return anything?

**EDIT**

Here's a more complicated example - which also doesn't return anything

```
discounts = [

  {
    sku: "126D",
    title: "Discount for using 126",
    discountCode: "LOVE126",
    discountAmount: -2500,
    check: function(orderFormContents, callback) {

      var discountsApplied = orderFormContents.discountsApplied;
      var sqft = orderFormContents.propertyInfo.sqft;

      for (var i = discountsApplied.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (discountsApplied[i].discountCode === this.discountCode) {
          if (sqft < 1501) {
            return callback('', 'Coupon Added', this.discountAmount);
          } else {
            return callback('', 'Coupon Added', (this.discountAmount + -2500));
          };
        };
      };

    }
  },

  // additional discount objects in array


];

var checkDiscount = function(code, orderFormContents, allDiscounts) {
  for (var i = allDiscounts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (allDiscounts[i].discountCode === code) {
      allDiscounts[i].check(orderFormContents, function(error, message, amount) {
          var result = {
            "error": error,
            "message": message,
            "amount": amount
          };
          debugger
          return result;
      });
    };
  };
};

var orderFormContents = {
  propertyInfo: {
    sqft: 1000
  },
  discountsApplied: [
    {
      discountCode: "LOVE126"
    }
  ]
};

var discountCode = "LOVE126";

var result = checkDiscount(discountCode, orderFormContents, discounts);
debugger
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @JasonWilczak Nothing about this code example is asynchronous.

Comment: typically the thing using the callback doesn't even bother to check the return. in theory, its possible, but ive never seen any lib or real code take advantage of it, like for loggin an "exit code" or something

Comment: @Oka Thanks for noticing :) I completely misread the problem and removed my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the return statement in `myFunc`.

```
var myFunc = function(input, callback){
  var sum = input + 10;
  return callback(sum);
};

sum = myFunc(1000, function(input){
  console.log(input);
  return input + 9000;
});
```

For extra clarification, there's nothing terribly special about your callback in this example. If you chain functions, you just need to make sure you `return` each result. We could rewrite the current example as:

```
function myInnerFunc(sum) {
  return sum + 9000;
}

function myFunc (input){
  var sum = input + 10;
  return myInnerFunc(sum);
}

var sum = myFunc(1000);
```

But, the nature of first-class functions in JavaScript allows us to pass functions around. This becomes interesting in functional programming, where one function can now be passed various other functions for different results.

```
function add (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function multi (a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(list.reduce(add)); // 15
console.log(list.reduce(multi)); // 120
```

Asynchronous operations fire their callbacks at some later time, so they can't be used to return values right away. The easiest example of this is `setTimeout` which calls its callback after `N` milliseconds. In this example `myFunc` will have returned long before the `setTimeout` has had a chance to fire its callback. Same logic can be applied to AJAX callbacks.

```
function myFunc (value) {
  var val;
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    val = value;
  }, 1000)
  return val;
}

var test = myFunc(1000)

console.log(test); // undefined
```

---

## Answer Part 2: Electric Boogaloo

You're still missing a `return`.

This line

```
var result = checkDiscount(discountCode, orderFormContents, discounts);
```

assigns the result from `checkDiscount`, but that function doesn't return anything.

```
var checkDiscount = function(code, orderFormContents, allDiscounts) {
  for (var i = allDiscounts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (allDiscounts[i].discountCode === code) {
      allDiscounts[i].check(orderFormContents, function(error, message, amount) {
        var result = {
          "error": error,
          "message": message,
          "amount": amount
        };
        return result;
      });
    }
  }
  // Never returned, default return value is undefined
};
```

You can fix this by returning properly.

```
var checkDiscount = function(code, orderFormContents, allDiscounts) {
  for (var i = allDiscounts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (allDiscounts[i].discountCode === code) {
      return allDiscounts[i].check(orderFormContents, function(error, message, amount) {
        var result = {
          "error": error,
          "message": message,
          "amount": amount
        };
        return result;
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Honestly, this code is really looptastic, and could most likely be refactored into something more concise.

Comment: hmmm... interesting. I guess this is the part that's a bit confusing for me. When I'm doing `return callback(sum)` it's basically doing: `return function(input){
  console.log(input);
  return input + 9000;
}` oh nevermind it makes total sense now.

Comment: Basically, running the function returns a value, but then you need to immediately return *that* value. However, this will NOT work if the logic inside the callback is actually asynchronous, right?

Comment: Yes, asynchronous operations have to be resolved at a later time.

Comment: OK, I added a more complicated example to the OP. There's nothing async going on inside the code, but it's still not returning anything.

Comment: Oh, wait... I have a sneaky suspicion that it's not returning anything because I'm using `this` when calling the callback, huh? The `context` of `this` at this point is different... or something?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny Added a part two to the answer.

Comment: I see... I thought that placing a `return` inside of a for loop would automatically return the value and stop all code execution? I still have to return the value outside of the loop? Also, because I'm using `this.discountAmount`, do I have to use `.apply()` to make sure `this` does not change context to something like the window object or something?